# firefox doesn't download jar file

Tags: java, firefox

I have on my website a link to a jar file that I want to download to my desktop. In internet explorer it download the jar. But when I do the same with firefox it doesn't download the jar file. It just open the jar file in the browser and then I see a lot of questionmarks and weird signs. do someone know how to make sure firefox download the jar, instead of opening it? Here is the [link of the jar](http://www.freewhist.be/jars/FreeWhistClient.jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the link and save it using 'Save link as (K)', the jar file will be saved on your computer.

Comment: is there no comment like we have target="_blank" or something like that, that does that?

Comment: @Bigjo only outerHTML: "<a href=\"http://www.freewhist.be/jars/FreeWhistClient.jar\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer\">link of the jar</a>" and target="".